# Why the code getting executed under `if( savedData != null )`, no matter if `savedData` is set to any value or null

Tags: java, android

I am learning Android but i am not much experienced with java.
I write these code to check if there is any data in `sharedPreferences` (Which i saved before using `sharedPreferences.Editor`) or not, and if there is any saved data then do something. But the code under `if (savedData != null)` Statement is always being executed, no matter if there is any value in `savedData` or not.

But when i use `if (!savedData.isEmpty()` it is doing what i meant it to do.

But i found on StackOverflow that we should not use `isEmpty()` with String because if String is `null` then `isEmpty()` will not execute.

I just wanted to know why `if (savedData != null)` is not working but `if (!savedData.isEmpty())`.

My code: Here `Log.d("isRunning : ", "True")` under `if` statement is always executing.

```
private String saveString = null;
    private ListView listView;
    private static List<String> listArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private SaveListInSharedPreferences saveListInSharedPreferences = new SaveListInSharedPreferences();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedData = settings.getString(saveString, null);
    if (savedData != null){
        listArray = saveListInSharedPreferences.getList(savedData);
        Log.d("isRunning : ", "True" );
    }
```

Comment: Clearly it is not null in preferences, otherwise it wouldn't go there. Why do you assume it would be?

Comment: I think you should start with Java basics before you face many such issues. Anyways the way to use both the above conditions is to chain them with a && (put the NULL check on LEFT) -  `if (savedData != null && !savedData.isEmpty())`

Comment: I am assigning `null` to `savedData`. in first line there is `saveString` to  `null` then i am assigning this `saveString` to `savedData` in line 12 using `String savedData = settings.getString(saveString, null);`. what i am doing wrong there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (myString != null && !myString.isEmpty()) {
    //
}
```

If this doesn't work then it isn't null. If it's not working then try setting it directly equal to null beforehand, and then figuring out why that function isn't returning null
. 
As to why myString != null doesn't work by itself, here's a post that can explain it better than I could. 
[Avoiding != null statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements)